# Is there a way to use Facebook Presto 0.131 with Cassandra 3.0.0?

Tags: cassandra, presto, cassandra-3.0

When querying a Cassandra 3.0.0 cluster using Presto 0.131 I get:

All host(s) tried for query failed [..snip...] InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces

I assume this is due to some change in Cassandra's system schemas? If so is there a workaround or should we wait for Presto to support Cassandra 3.0.0?

**2016-11-05 Update** : Newer versions of PrestoDB work fine with Cassandra 3+. Currently using 0.147 but [the latest version](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html) is 0.156 and they all work fine with the new protocol. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: did you get presto working with cassandra3 on Thrift protocol, or native protocol? I suppose Thrift, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you guessed correctly - there was a change in schema storage between Cassandra 2.2.4 and 3.0.0. See [here](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-224) for more information. The actual change to the schema is described in [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6717).