# How to downgrade Cassandra 3.0.0 -> 2.x?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

[I recently found out that Cassandra 3.0.0 and PrestoDB don't play well together.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611382/is-there-a-way-to-use-facebook-presto-0-131-with-cassandra-3-0-0)

I have a lot of data loaded into Cassandra 3.0 and I wouldn't like to rebuild the whole thing. Is there a safe way to downgrade to 2.x temporarily until Presto is updated, so then I can come back to 3.0?

I know downgrading is not officially supported, but I'm wondering whether more experienced S.O. Cassandra users could point me in the right direction here. I assume the answer will be "don't try it", but who knows, maybe there's a way. Thanks in advance.

**Update 2016-11-05** : Using version 0.147 and newer of PrestoDB and this issue has been solved. In the end I did not need to downgrade Cassandra in order to use PrestoDB. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Is this a new installation?  Or did you upgrade from 2.x?  And if you upgraded, did you run `nodetool upgradesstables`?

Comment: Hi Aaron, yes this is a new install, but thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've started with 3.0, the only way I can think of is to export all your data then reimport it.  The storage format has massively changed and 2.x can't read the 3.0 tables.

Unfortunately sstable2json was removed in 3.0, so you'll probably need to export it all manually then import into a previous version.

Comment: Mr Haddad is, of course, correct here. With 3.0, the cqlsh `COPY` performance is almost respectable - depending on the size of your data (ie: will it fit on a single server), you may be able to `COPY` it out, then `COPY` it back in. Failing that, you can use alternative implementations of sstable2json (such as https://github.com/tolbertam/sstable-tools ) to export the data to json, then rebuild the cluster, and then write it back in with the programming language of your choice.

Comment: Thank you for the COPY command suggestion, Jeff. Will have a look at this.

Comment: Just a quick comment to update this issue : since PrestoDB 0.147 I no longer have issues between Presto and Cassandra 3+. I've updated Cassandra as well and they play together fine now. Thanks for your replies.