# Downgrading to Cassandra 2

Tags: database, cassandra, debian

So I screwed up and accidentally upgraded our Cassandra 2 box to Cassandra 3. The data is all intact but I need to get it back to Cassandra 2 for compatibility with other tools. I read the post here [How to downgrade Cassandra 3.0.0 -> 2.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34634932/how-to-downgrade-cassandra-3-0-0-2-x) and I'm ok with having to manually float the data around if that's what it takes (it's not THAT much data).

The upgrade was accidentally done using `apt-get dist-upgrade` but nothing was done afterwards, there's a comment asking about using `nodetool`, it wasn't run unless it's part of the `apt-get process`. I know just about 0 about managing Cassandra.

I've built a new Cassandra 2 server with the following versions:

```
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.17 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
```

The Cassandra 3 server is on versions:

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.6 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]
```

I used the `COPY` command to export all of the *data* into CSV files and used the `DESC` on the keyspace to have it show all the tables and their respective headers and types.

If I try to use the `.cql` file I created from the `DESC` command to rebuild the keyspace and tables, it fails:

```
cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra -f "mykeyspace.cql"
mykeyspace.cql:22:Bad Request: Unknown property 'crc_check_chance'
mykeyspace.cql:40:Bad Request: Unknown property 'crc_check_chance'
mykeyspace.cql:57:Bad Request: Unknown property 'crc_check_chance'
...
```

It appears to create the keyspace as I can browse it in `cqlsh` but it doesn't have any tables so I can't import the data from CSV.

I thought maybe the crc_check_chance was a new thing introduced in 3.x, so I tried removing it and re-running the `.cql` file after dropping the keyspace, but it still fails, just on some other option.

What can I do to get this data back into Cassandra 2?

EDIT: Here's one table from the export I have from my (current) Cassandra 3 instance:

```
CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.users (
    username text PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name text,
    last_name text,
    roles set<text>
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

This fails, but if I remove the following fields, it seems to build the table:

```
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
```

Even though the table is created, the data fails to import from CSV, which could be me not using the command correctly:

```
cqlsh> USE mykeyspace;
cqlsh:mykeyspace> COPY users FROM '/home/user/cassandra/users.csv';
Bad Request: line 1:118 no viable alternative at input ')'
Aborting import at record #0 (line 1). Previously-inserted values still present.
```

Comment: Have you already ran nodetool <options> upgradesstables ?

Comment: Not explicitly. I also don't know if that's included ins the apt-get upgrade sequence though.

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like it was accidentally upgraded by `apt-get upgrade` which does not automatically run `nodetool upgradesstables` (that is a manual step see the [upgrade guide](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-upgrade/upgrade/cassandra/upgradeCassandraDetails.html) #9 which is ran after updating via APT).

So you should be able to do the following:

1. Required Caution: First backup your data for your cluster before continuing (just in case)
2. Find which Cassandra version you want to downgrade to `apt-cache showpkg cassandra`
3. Downgrade your binaries to the older version `sudo apt-get install cassandra=<desired-cassandra-version>`
4. Validate that Cassandra is the older version and it works
5. Tell APT to pin your package version to avoid future disaster with `apt-mark hold cassandra`

Comment: I tried this and it seems like apt did the trick to install, but cassandra is failing to start and I'm not able to use cqlsh on the node.

Comment: I believe that APT would've overwritten your config files during the upgrade process [from the debian upgrade subsection](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-upgrade/upgrade/cassandra/upgradeDebC_t.html#task_ds_rvs_qzr_ck). So I would double check that your config files are set as you would expect it.

Comment: I think it's beyond fixable at this point. Maybe? I'm getting the following error in the log with as close to a fresh install of Cassandra without nuking the data I care about: `CassandraDaemon.java:638 - Detected unreadable sstables /var/lib/cassandra/data/mykeyspace...` If i reformat the log to make it a bit more readable, it's yelling that all the tables are messed up and finishes with `please check NEWS.txt and ensure that you have upgraded through all required intermediate versions`. I don't think I can run an upgrade given it can't connect with broken tables can I?

Comment: Probably a bit late for OP, but for anyone reading this:
Although the old sstables stay there and can be read by older versions, any new writes happen to new-format sstables that cant' be read by older versions.  In addition, I believe any compactions that happen will result in new-format sstables that can't be read by the older version.